# Connecting to EXASOL from AWS/Lambda/.NETCore/C#/ADO.Net/Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, exasolution

I am writing an AWS Lambda function in Visual Studio 2017 and C# that needs to execute an Exasol script.  I think my problem is figuring out which Assemblies and NuGet packages to reference.

I’ve installed: EXASolution_ADO.NET-5.0.17.msi and I’m referencing Microsoft.NETCore.app 1.0, System.Data.Common and EXADataProvider.dll.

In this code:

```
var exasolCnx = new Exasol.EXADataProvider.EXAConnection();
var exasolCmd = exasolCnx.CreateCommand();
```

The first line works and gives me a EXAConnection object.

The second line gives two compile errors:

- The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not
  referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
- 'EXAConnection' does not contain a definition for
  'CreateCommand' and no extension method 'CreateCommand' accepting a
  first argument of type 'EXAConnection' could be found (are you
  missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I really need to dig up a reference to System.Data version 2.0.0.0?  The oldest readily available version on NuGet is 4.0.